# Maths algorithm for scaling to a percentage from variable values

Tags: javascript, math

Right, you will have to stick with me because I am confusing myself at the moment.

I am trying to work out the scale of an svg when I add it to a rapheal paper element.

Here's what needs to happen:

All of my SVGs are variable widths.
When I add them to my paper object I want them to be 600px wide. I need to calculate the scale ratio of the original width that will always work out at 600px, whether the original width is 2000px or 10px.

What I have so far is...

```
    var maxWidth = 600;
    var vWidth = vector.getBBox().width //this could be anything;

    //Instert algorithym to work out the scale ratio
    //I am not smart enough to work this part out. Please help...
    //Currently this scale s set to what the original width is, but I want it to always be 600

    vector.scale(1, 1);
```

I hope this makes sense to somebody! I am a designer who turned programmer (as you can probably tell)

Thanks!

Comment: `w * c = 600 => c = 600 / w`, where `c` your scalar and `w` your width

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, in the header you want percentage, then in the code you've ratio, which one you actually want?

Answer (score 1):

If you divide 600 by the width of your element, it'll tell you by how much you need to scale it to make 600. I'm sure you're smart enough for the coding part :)

Examples:

- Element has a width of 100px, so you need it to make it 6 times bigger. 600/100 is 6.
- Element has a width of 1800px, so you need to make it 3 times smaller. 600/1800 is 1/3, so you're good too.

Comment: Yeah, it all makes sense now!!! You know how it is when your over thinking something.

I'll post back with my app in a few days : )

Thanks again. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Sure thing. Consider [marking answers as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (for this question and your other questions) if you consider your problem solved.

Comment: Hi zneak, I just wanted to post a link to the site you helped me with. I was using repheal in the "Create a decal" section

http://guitarraps.com

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var maxWidth = 600;
var vWidth = vector.getBBox().width;
var xscale=600/vWidth;

vector.scale(xscale, 1);
```